# iterating on glob set doesn't work with if condition

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, glob

l have a column composed of a set of string as follow :

```
npa = pd.read_csv("file_names.csv", usecols=[3,5,6, 7, 8, 9], header=None)
npa.iloc[:,0]
XML_0_1841729699_001
XML_0_1841729699_00nn
XML_0_1841729699_00145
XML_0_1841729699_00145
XML_0_1841729699_00178
XML_0_1841729699_001jklm
XML_0_1841729699_001fjmfd
```

and l have png names as follow :

```
path_img = "/images"
os.chdir(path_img)
images_name = glob.glob("*.png")
set_img = set([x.rsplit('.', 1)[0] for x in images_name])
set_img
set(['XML_0_1841729699_001fjmfd', XML_0_1841729699_00145','XML_0_1841729699_001','XML_0_1841729699_00178'])
```

l want to check that the name in `set_img` matches the one in the dataframe before doing a processing :

```
for i in range(1, 30):
    for img_name in set_img:
        if (img_name==npa.iloc[i,0]):  # 0 corresponds to the the column of string 
            print("it works")
```

However it doesn't check the condition if. 
What's wrong ?

EDIT1:

```
f = open("file_names.csv", 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    if cpt >= 1:  # skip header
        characs.append(str(row[5]))
    cpt += 1

path_img = "/images"
os.chdir(path_img)
images_name = glob.glob("*.png")
set_img = set([x.rsplit('.', 1)[0] for x in images_name])
mask = npa.iloc[:,0].isin(set_img)
for img in set_img:

    img = cv2.imread(path_img+'/'+ img +'.png')
    print(img.shape)

    images = []
    images_names = []
    WIDTH=[]
    HEIGHT=[]

    for i in range(1, nb_charac):
        if (img==npa[mask].iloc[i,0]):
            print("hello")
            coords = npa.iloc[[i]]
            charac = characs[i - 1]
```

l got the following errors :

```
 FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  if (img==npa[mask].iloc[i,0]):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/to_test.py", line 186, in <module>
    if (img==npa[mask].iloc[i,0]):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1225, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1449, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 127, in _has_valid_tuple
    if not self._has_valid_type(k, i):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1417, in _has_valid_type
    return self._is_valid_integer(key, axis)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1431, in _is_valid_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

EDIT2:
```

then l replaced :

```
if (img==npa[mask].iloc[i,0]):
```

by

```
if (img==npa[mask][3][i]):
```

it works until a certain row and l got the following error :

```
    if (img==npa[mask][3][i]):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 557, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1790, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 103, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3204)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2903)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3843)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 303, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6525)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 309, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6463)
KeyError: 2035
```

Comment: In your if statement, you dropped `iloc`, it should read `if(img_name==npa.iloc[i,0])`.

Comment: sorry i didn't wrote it well. actually in my code l did if(img_name==npa.iloc[i,0])

Answer (score 2):

Use `isin` to create a Boolean mask. Then use that mask to filter the dataframe.  This is equivalent to looping through each row and checking if the first column is in the set.

```
mask = npa.iloc[:,0].isin(set_img)
npa[mask]
```

Comment: Not sure to understand your answer. how can l use it in my for loop in if condition is it if (img_name==npa[mask]): ?

Comment: l think it's if (img==npa[mask].iloc[i,0]):

Comment: @vincent your loop doesn't do anything but print. I am giving you a method to check the condition for every row at one time. Then you can reduce the dataframe to only those rows in which the condition is true. This is a very typical pre processing step. Your question was not entirely clear because you're not producing anything.

Comment: DEFINITELY, l updated my code. please see the update